# Input elements overflow bootstrap grid system cells?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

[Here is an example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ELefEjO/1/)

I am trying to use the bootstrap grid system and I'm finding that input elements oveflow the grid cells. Is there something that I'm supposed to do to prevent this? Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8"></div>
      <div class="span2">per Invoice</div>  
      <div class="span2">per LB</div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8">
        <select>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <div class="span2">
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm aware that setting `input,select,textarea { max-length: 100%}` fixes the issue but it seems like an odd oversight on bootstrap's behalf. Odd enough that it's likely I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if it's possible to limit the amount of characters that can be entered into the input field. If not, then I apologize. This is how you would do that:

```
<input data-bind="" maxlength="10">
```

This sets the maximum number of characters that can be input into that field to 10, or whatever integer you want to put in there.

**EDIT:**

Or if the problem is that the input field is visually too long, you can do the following:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span7"></div>
      <div class="span2">per Invoice</div>  
      <div class="span2 offset1">per LB</div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span7">
        <select>
          <option>Suggested Freight - <span></span></option>
          <option>Enter Freight</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <div class="span2">
        <input data-bind="" maxlength="10">
      </div>
      <div class="span2 offset1">
        <input data-bind="" maxlength="10">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This just spaces it out slightly and the fields stay within the specified grid. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: No, this is not at all what I'm asking - what I'm asking is why do my input elements overflow the bootstrap grid system? Is this by design? Setting maxlength will 1) limit my input length (which I do not want) and 2) will still cause the inputs to overflow when the screen is small enough in width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your inputs to fit in the grid you can give `span` class to your inputs as well.

`<input data-bind="" class="span12">`